# mscorlib dll faild to add in silverlight application reference

Tags: silverlight-5.0, mscorlib

I removed mscorlib library(dll) by mistake from my silverlight application's reference.
Now I am trying to add the same library again,but not able to add.When I click on add button after selecting the library in .net assemblies reference , add item window closes without adding the library.
What could be the problem and solution. 
Do I need to re install silverlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open the silverlight applications .csproject file in notepadd++ and add
 tag in  tag where all the references are given.Rebuild the solution and its done.